# Windows 7 независимая программа на втором мониторе

Tags: windows

вобщем есть программа выведенная на другом мониторе, но я  по прежнему могу ее свернуть через alt+tab, если эта программа является игрой то она остановится пока я к ней не вернусь. Кстати эта программа так же может блокировать работу с окнами в основном мониторе.

силами win7 можно сделать так чтоб эта запущенная программа не мешала пользоваться компьютером, и пользователь не мешал работе этой программы?
возможно win10 может мне помочь? там же сделали виртуальные рабочие столы

Comment: *если эта программа является игрой то она остановится пока я к ней не вернусь* -- обычно синглплеерные игры следят, в фокусе ли их окно, и останавливаются, если нет. Так что виртуальные рабочие столы не помогут. Да и другие штатные решения, скорее всего. И чтобы хоть что-то сделать, скорее всего, потребуется держать игру в оконном режиме или в виртуальной машине. Но-о... зачем такие сложности?

Comment: виртуальная машина хорошо, но она не умеет выводить звук на другое аудио устройство

Comment: это вопрос настройки вывода звука в ОС, виртуалке действительно нечего таким заниматься :)

Comment: я поставил эмулятор консольных игр на компьютер, но выделять целый компьютер для эмулятора как то глупо. к тому же если монитор не один. Вот я решил замутить нечто подобное. Сначала я конечно поставил виртуалбокс, но потом оказалось что он может выводить звук только на устройство по умолчанию((((

Comment: я не нашел ниодной программы какая смогла бы роутить звук с виртуалбокса. с хрома запросто, винамп сам умеет.  но виртуалбокс никак.